Vtiger custom module dosn't show in main menu
I ran this script from Vtiger to create a custom module:
https://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/extensions/examples/entity-module.html
But dosen't show in main menu under "tools link"
i got this message even :
Creating Module Expenses ... STARTED
Initializing module permissions ... DONE
Updating tabdata file ... DONE
Setting up sharing access options ... DONE
Added to menu Tools ... DONE
Updating parent_tabdata file ... STARTED
Updating parent_tabdata file ... DONE
Creating Module Expenses ... DONE
Creating Block LBL_EXPENSES_INFORMATION ... DONE
Module language entry for LBL_EXPENSES_INFORMATION ... CHECK
Creating Block LBL_CUSTOM_INFORMATION ... DONE
Module language entry for LBL_CUSTOM_INFORMATION ... CHECK
Creating Field summary ... DONE
Module language mapping for Summary ... CHECK
Setting entity identifier ... DONE
Creating Field expenseon ... DONE
Module language mapping for Expense On ... CHECK
Creating Field expenseamount ... DONE
Module language mapping for Amount ... CHECK
Creating Field description ... DONE
Module language mapping for Description ... CHECK
Creating Field assigned_user_id ... DONE
Module language mapping for Assigned To ... CHECK
Creating Field createdtime ... DONE
Module language mapping for Created Time ... CHECK
Creating Field modifiedtime ... DONE
Module language mapping for Modified Time ... CHECK
Creating Field source ... DONE
Module language mapping for Source ... CHECK
Creating Field starred ... DONE
Module language mapping for starred ... CHECK
Creating Field tags ... DONE
Module language mapping for tags ... CHECK
Creating Filter All ... DONE
Setting Filter All to status [0] ... DONE
Adding summary to All filter ... DONE
Adding expenseon to All filter ... DONE
Adding description to All filter ... DONE
Adding assigned_user_id to All filter ... DONE
Recalculating sharing rules ... DONE
Initializing webservices support ...DONE
OK

It shows "Added to menu Tools ... DONE", but I can see anything.
please help me...
